# how to put multiple variables in if statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, double

I'm super new to programming , I'm making a program to calculate If two lines are parallel or not, the lines are considered parallel if **a1 b2 = a2 b1**
but I don't know how to put multiple variables in one if statement
I have searched but I didn't find the answer
can you help me please?

```
if (a1 && b2 == a2 && b1)
    System.out.print("the lines are parallel");
else System.out.print("the lines are not parallel");
```

Comment: If you find our answers helpful, don't forget to accept them - click the checkmark next to an answer - so that people will know this problem is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does **a1 b2 = a2 b1** mean?

### It means: If a1 multiplied by b2 equals a2 multiplied by b1

Then program that: `a1 * b2 == a2 * b1`. The habit of assuming 'multiply' when you put entries right next to each other is a math thing. In java that does not work; If you want to multiply, `*` is what you want.

### It means: if a1 equals b2, and a2 equals b1

Then program that: `&&` is 'and', as in, given two true/false values, you can use the `&&` operator to reduce them to a single true/false value (true if  both are true, false otherwise). Just like `5 + 7` reduces two numbers to one number, `true && false` does the same. Thus, you can't use `&&` as "and" in the sense of "if a and b are equal to c" (because 'a' is not a true/false value). Thus:

`(a1 == b2) && (b1 == a2)`

### Etcetera

You get the gist - between `==` and `&&` and perhaps some parentheses, you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If your line equation is `y = ax + b` then lines are parallel if `a1 == a2` so your 'if statement' should be `if (a1 == a2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want parallel lines all you need is `if (a1 == a2)`, the `b1` and `b2` don't matter.

However, if you want to check if the numbers multiplied together are equal use:

```
if ((a1 * b1) == (a2 * b2)) System.out.print("the lines are parallel");
```

and the compiler will calculate the expressions inside the parenthesis first before checking for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do write the if statement as follows:

```
if((a1==b2)&&(a2==b1))
```